# IIS, DNS, Authentication

Tags: iis, authentication

Not really sure what's going on so I'm going to just list my setup then my symptoms.

We are running IIS 6.0 on Server 2003 on 2 identical servers.  We run multiple websites on each server (Same sites).  They are load balanced equally.

Servers;
  (Servername)WebFarm1 (IP)10.1.254.101
  (Servername)WebFarm2 (IP)10.1.254.102
  Load balancer = 10.1.254.100

We have internal DNS records which resolve URL to the load balance IP.

DNS Entry
  (URL)WebSite1 resolves to 10.1.254.100

WebSite1 has windows authentication configured.

The Problem;

When a client PC navigates to http://WebSite1 - it works fine

when a client PC navigates to http://WebFarm1 - it works fine (but obviously only shows default website)

When WebFarm1 (remote desktop) navigates to http://localhost - it works fine

When WebFarm1 (remote desktop) navigates to http://WebSite1 - windows credentials are requested

My guess is the windows credentials are being lost as the server is either trying to connect the other web server or the url request is being directed back out to the load balancer and then back in.  But I don't know why this would cause the credentials to be lost.

This was working correctly on our previous setup but we have new servers and a new load balancer (I've not been involved to much in the network setup, but we're all stumped).

Any help or ideas would be hugely appreciated as we've moved to this server farm now and we are getting some remaining issues which I believe are a request of this problem.

Many thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would have anything to do with it or not, but at what layer is your load balancer running the Virtual Service? Is it running at Layer 4 or Layer 7? Again I am not sure why this would make a difference but maybe. Also, something else you might want to check (if you are running at Layer 7) would be whether or not you have IP transparency turned on, if you don't then the situation you describe when on the local server and having it reroute back through the LB maybe could have something to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I'll get one of my guys to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try pinging http://WebSite1 on WebFarm1.
Try pinging http://WebSite1 on a client.
Also try a tracert on both
Wat are the results?

Does the server have multiple network cards?